# Reshaping 2D numpy array to 4D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a 2D numpy array `X` (`batch x channels` х `pool_size * pool_size`),
where first row corresponds to the first channel in first batch, second row -
to the second channel in the first batch, third row - to the first channel
in the second batch and the last - to the second channel in the second batch:

```
[[ 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 0, 3, 0], 
 [ 0, 0, 0, 4]]
```

Is it possible to convert it into 4D array `Y` (`batch` x `pool_size` x `pool_size` x `channels`)
without any loops using only numpy methods so that
`Y[0, :, :, 0]` is

```
[[1, 0],
[0, 0]]
```

`Y[0, :, :, 1]` is

```
[[0, 2], 
[0, 0]]
```

`Y[1, :, :, 0]` is

```
[[0, 0], 
[3, 0]]
```

`Y[1, :, :, 1]` is

```
[[0, 0], 
[0, 4]]
```

UPD: For the input array

```
[[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [ 9, 10, 11, 12], 
 [ 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

expected results are:
`Y[0, :, :, 0]` is

```
[[1, 2],
[3, 4]]
```

`Y[0, :, :, 1]` is

```
[[5, 6], 
[7, 8]]
```

`Y[1, :, :, 0]` is

```
[[9, 10], 
[11, 12]]
```

`Y[1, :, :, 1]` is

```
[[13, 14], 
[15, 16]]
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

this do what you need it too?

Comment: @sntrenter no, X.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)[0, :, :, 1] and X.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)[1, :, :, 0] don't give results I mentioned in the question.

Comment: With [`einops`](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/einops) you can literally translate your requirements to `Y = einops.rearrange(X,'(b c) (p p1) -> b p p1 c', b=2, c=2, p=2)`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thanks but i'm looking for a numpy solution

Comment: `X.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,3,1)`, but this is not easy to follow for beginners. I would recommend `einops` as it is becoming the industry standard.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny please look at the updated question: I changed it for a more general case

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yeah, my mistake, you're right! Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0],28,28,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reshape and then use the swapaxes.

```
A = np.array([[ 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 0, 3, 0], 
 [ 0, 0, 0, 4]])
B = A.reshape(2,2,2, 2)
```

Here is the output:

```
array([[[[1, 0],
     [0, 0]],

    [[0, 2],
     [0, 0]]],


   [[[0, 0],
     [3, 0]],

    [[0, 0],
     [0, 4]]]])
```

2:

```
array([[[[ 1,  2],
     [ 3,  4]],

    [[ 5,  6],
     [ 7,  8]]],


   [[[ 9, 10],
     [11, 12]],

    [[13, 14],
     [15, 16]]]])
```

Comment: I expected that A = np.array([[ 0, 1, 0, 0], [ 0, 1, 0, 0], [ 0, 1, 0, 0],  [ 0, 0, 1, 0]])
B = A.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2).swapaxes(0, 2) will give me B[0, :, :, 0] == [[0, 1], [0, 0]], B[0, :, :, 1] == [[0, 1], [0, 0]], B[1, :, :, 0] == [[0, 1], [0, 0]], B[1, :, :, 1] == [[0, 0], [1, 0]], but It doesn't =(

Comment: i've just updated my question for a more general case

Comment: So, with this new case, it seems that you only need the reshape. Check the answer now.